# Fetch message with specified key using Kafka Listener vs Kafka Consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I use a SpringBoot App to produce or consume/listen to Kafka
   messages.

I produce a message in the topic and consume/listen to the
   specific message by comparing the messageKey and then send the
   consumed message for further processing.

I am stuck with what approach will be better suited to my requirement to get specific message i.e. **Kafka Listener** or **Kafka Consumer** what ?

Answer (score 0):

KafkaListener is a Spring specific concept that wraps the Kafka Consumer API.

There is no way to get a message by a particular offset given the key. You must calculate the partition, then scan the entire offset